# Recorrer un JSON y retornarlo como un ARRAY

Tags: php, ajax, json, poo

Muy buenas noches caballeros, estoy realizando un buscador con ***AJAX***, pero estoy teniendo un pequeño inconveniente con lo que me esta retornando los datos de mi método, quiero mostrar una tabla que se recargue en vivo y estoy recibiendo lo que se escribe en un input y enviándolo a un archivo que lo procesa por medio de un método en **PHP** y su respectiva conexión es **PDO**. Cuando realizo la consulta a la bd y retorno el valor del método para darle la respuesta a **ajax** me dice que pocos argumentos para funcionar el **foreach** y si lo hago con un **while** aparece otro error que accedo a la clase de un objeto.

Este es el archivo que le mando los datos de AJAX

```
introducir el código aquí
<?php
require('clases/Paciente.php');
$objeto1 = new clases\Paciente();

$salida = ""; 

if(isset($_POST['consulta'])){ 
$resultado = $objeto1->conBusqueda($_POST['consulta']);  
$salida.="<table border=1 class='tabla_datos'>
        <thead>
            <tr id='titulo'>
                <td>id_paciente</td>
                <td>nombre</td>
                <td>edad</td>
                <td>foto</td>
                <td>peso</td>
            </tr>

        </thead>


<tbody>";

foreach ($resultado as $fila) {
    $salida.="<tr>
    <td>".$fila['id_paciente']."</td>
    <td>".$fila['nombre']."</td>
    <td>".$fila['edad']."</td>
    <td>".$fila['foto']."</td>
    <td>".$fila['peso']."</td>
    </tr>";
}
$salida.="</tbody></table>";}


echo $salida;
```

**Nota:** Se supone que aquí estoy capturando los  datos que llegan por **POST['consulta']** del buscador o mejor dicho mi cuadro de texto, y entonces yo valido si esta declarado este mismo y por medio de **objeto1** llamo a mi metodo **conBusqueda()** EL cual posee los datos de mi enviados por **POST** en AJAX, posteriormente este método lo trabaja de esta forma.

```
introducir el código aquí
public function conBusqueda($q)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM paciente WHERE id_paciente LIKE %:q% OR nombre 
    LIKE %:q% OR edad LIKE '%:q%' OR foto LIKE %:q% OR peso LIKE ':q' ";
    $stmn = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
    $stmn->bindParam(":q", $q, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmn->execute();
    return $stmn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

En este lugar le digo que espera un dato que sera almacenado en **$q**, después declaro mi **SQL** en una variable llamo a mi **stament** y preparo la consulta, paso el valor a los marcadores con el **bindParam** ejecuto y retorno de forma *ASOCIATIVA*, pero cuando quiero recorrer ya con el **foreach** los datos, aparecen los errores mencionados anteriormente

**Nota:** Por favor si alguien me quiere ayudar me ayudaría demasiado si no lo realiza con **mysqli** sino con **PDO** y que lo trabajara algo parecido a lo que yo estoy realizando o me explicara en que estoy fallando.

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿Porqué usas `LIKE` en tu consulta?

Comment: El problema no es PDO, el cual es incluso mucho más fácil e intuitivo que mysqli. El problema es la lógica que aplicas. Primeramente, como comenta @MauricioContreras, tu consulta con todos esos `LIKE` es rara. Luego, el manejo que haces para obtener los datos también es raro. ¿Por qué sales del contexto de `conBusqueda` para trabajar los datos en otro sitio? Además, si como dices, estás trabajando con Ajax, lo mejor sería simplificar. En vez de construir la tabla en el servidor, guarda los datos en un JSON, devuélvelos a Ajax y construye la tabla del lado del cliente, así es más ligero.

Comment: Además, la consulta no se puede preparar así, cuando usas `LIKE` tienes que pasar los comodines con el dato, no en la consulta. La forma más simple en tu caso sería esta (pasando un array): `$sql = "SELECT * FROM paciente WHERE id_paciente LIKE ? OR nombre LIKE ? OR edad LIKE ? OR foto LIKE ? OR peso LIKE ? "; $arrParams=array("%$q%","%$q%","%$q%","%$q%","%$q%"); $stmn->execute($arrParams); //En lugar de hacer return, ¡trabaja los datos aquí!`  O sea, cada parámetro es independiente. Tu consulta espera 5 parámetros, aunque sea el mismo, porque son 5 LIKES los que usas, no sé si me explico.

Comment: La verdad es que eso es de un video que estaba viendo y lo que el esta haciendo es trabajando los datos en el mismo archivo php, pero con mysli y de forma estructurada y como yo trabajo orientado a objetos en php, pero mas nunca e trabajado con formato JSON ni con AJAX no entiendo muy bien algunas cosas, el link del vídeo que seguí es este: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OASBM4heElI

Comment: Creo que llego tarde, pero por las dudas pregunto ¿Ya te diste cuenta que el problema es que estas haciendo `$stmn->fetch` el cual retorna exactamente 1 registro y que deberias usar [`$stmn->fetchAll`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php) que devuelve un arreglo de registros?